# form ignores 'POST'

Tags: forms, post

so..I have a form with method='post' set.

```
<form action='/${languageLinkCode}html/reservation' method='POST' name='homeform'>
//fields
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

when i click the submit button, it always uses 'GET' instead of 'POST'

I've trieddocument.forms['homeform'].submit(); as well

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Best to always show the HTML as it appears in the browser, not the source which is going to be interpreted. `'/${languageLinkCode}html/reservation'` *is* a valid form action, but that's probably not the URL the form is being submitted to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no space before `name`. Please validate your HTML.

Comment: // that's my typo. There is space in the live website.

Comment: Please make a replica - I can't see anything wrong with that demo.

Comment: // um..i just tested in my local server. It works fine...is there any possibilities that the server is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between 'POST' and "name":

```
<form action='/${languageLinkCode}html/reservation' method='POST' name='homeform'>
```

Comment: // that is my typo. There is a space between POST and name in the live website.